# Find the tangent to the graph of the function which is perpendicular to the line

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, tangent-line

Find the tangent to the graph of the function $f (x) = \ln (x-1) ^ 2$ which is perpendicular to the line $p$: $y = \frac{2}{5}x +2$

I decided $kp = 2/5$ and planted in $kn = -1/kp = -5/2 \to kt = -5/2$. Then I derived the function $f'(x) = 2/(x-1)$.

Substituted into the equation
$kt = -5/2 = 2/(x-1) \to x=1/5$.
And put in the original function. And determined $y=\ln(16/25)$

Is this procedure correct and how do I express the tangent equation?

Comment: What does kp and kt mean? Have you forgotten to include these variables in your question?

Comment: that's a strange way to denote slopes $kt, kn$. However your working so far is correct. Now just write the equation of the line. You already know its slope $- \frac{5}{2}$ and you also have a point on the line $(\frac{1}{5}, \ln {\frac{16}{25}})$.

Comment: These are tangent, normal and straight line directions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we want to find a tangent to $f(x) = \ln ((x-1)^2)$ that has the slope of $\frac{-1}{2/5} = -\frac{5}{2}$. Indeed the derivative you got was correct, so we just need to find the point $(x, f(x))$ for which we have a tangent with the slope $-\frac{5}{2}$. So

$$ f'(x) = -\frac{5}{2} = \dfrac{2}{x-1} \implies x=\frac{1}{5} $$

So the point $\left(\frac{1}{5}, \ln \left(\frac{16}{25}\right)\right)$ has a tangent to $f(x)$ with the slope $-\frac{5}{2}$, So

$$ y -  \ln \left(\frac{16}{25}\right) = -\frac{5}{2}\left(x-\frac{1}{5}\right) $$

Comment: and that is the end result?

Comment: Correct. You just need to simplify it and write it as $ y = mx+b $

Comment: And I don't get anything for y anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure.